# How to make sure that table do not contain duplicates (based on two foreign keys)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, rails-api

I have three models:

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :component
end

class Size < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :component
end

class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ingredient
  belongs_to :size
end
```

My `schema.rb` looks like:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160414202240) do

  create_table "components", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean  "active"
    t.decimal  "cost"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.integer  "size_id"
    t.integer  "ingredient_id"
  end

  add_index "components", ["ingredient_id"], name: "index_components_on_ingredient_id"
  add_index "components", ["size_id"], name: "index_components_on_size_id"

  create_table "ingredients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "active"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "sizes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "active"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Now, I'm seeding the database with:

```
size_small = Size.create(name: 'Small', active: true)
size_medium = Size.create(name: 'Medium', active: true)
size_large = Size.create(name: 'Large', active: true)

ingredient_tomato = Ingredient.create(name: 'Tomato', active: true)
ingredient_onion = Ingredient.create(name: 'Onion', active: true)
ingredient_red_onion = Ingredient.create(name: 'Red onion', active: true)
ingredient_champignons = Ingredient.create(name: 'Champignons', active: true)
ingredient_shrimps = Ingredient.create(name: 'Shrimps', active: true)

Component.create(cost: 0.20, price: 1.00, active: true, size: size_small, ingredient: ingredient_tomato)
Component.create(cost: 0.20, price: 1.00, active: true, size: size_small, ingredient: ingredient_onion)
Component.create(cost: 0.20, price: 1.00, active: true, size: size_small, ingredient: ingredient_red_onion)
Component.create(cost: 0.30, price: 1.00, active: true, size: size_small, ingredient: ingredient_champignons)
Component.create(cost: 0.50, price: 1.50, active: true, size: size_small, ingredient: ingredient_shrimps)

Component.create(cost: 0.30, price: 1.50, active: true, size: size_medium, ingredient: ingredient_tomato)
Component.create(cost: 0.30, price: 1.50, active: true, size: size_medium, ingredient: ingredient_onion)
Component.create(cost: 0.30, price: 1.50, active: true, size: size_medium, ingredient: ingredient_red_onion)
Component.create(cost: 0.45, price: 1.50, active: true, size: size_medium, ingredient: ingredient_champignons)
Component.create(cost: 0.75, price: 2.25, active: true, size: size_medium, ingredient: ingredient_shrimps)

Component.create(cost: 0.40, price: 2.00, active: true, size: size_large, ingredient: ingredient_tomato)
Component.create(cost: 0.40, price: 2.00, active: true, size: size_large, ingredient: ingredient_onion)
Component.create(cost: 0.40, price: 2.00, active: true, size: size_large, ingredient: ingredient_red_onion)
Component.create(cost: 0.60, price: 2.00, active: true, size: size_large, ingredient: ingredient_champignons)
Component.create(cost: 1.00, price: 3.00, active: true, size: size_large, ingredient: ingredient_shrimps)

# This one uses again `size_small` and `ingredient_tomato` and shouldn't be allowed.
Component.create(cost: 2.99, price: 7.99, active: true, size: size_small, ingredient: ingredient_tomato)
```

What is the most `rails-api` way to validate that, the `size` and `ingredient` combined together should be unique in `Component` table?

Should I implement some logic in `Component`'s controller or it is possible to set some rules / scopes / whatever?

Please forgive my ignorance, I've just started to learn Ruby (and Rails).

I am using `Rails 4.2.6` with `Ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290)`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a scoped uniqueness validation to the model and a unique index to components table.

```
# app/models/component.rb
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validates :size_id, uniqueness: { scope: :ingredient_id } 
  ...
end

# app/db/migrate/20160412134948_add_uniqueness_index_to_components_table.rb
class AddUniquenessIndexToComponentsTable
  def change
    add_index :components, [:size_id, :ingredient_id], unique: true, name: 'components_uniqueness_validation'
  end
end
```

The reason you add the unique index is to ensure uniqueness with a multi-threaded server.  Here is an article where you can read more about thread safe uniqueness validations with Rails, http://www.kpheasey.com/2016/02/09/thread-safe-model-uniqueness-validations/

Comment: Thanks for a great hint. At least I have a good feelings about scopes. :-) One more question - should I do something in a model's controller to inform API users (trying to add such kind of repeated information using POST method) or Rails (with a help of above scope configuration) will return a valid HTTP return code (and maybe an error) by itself?

Comment: @tommus you don't need to do anything in the controller.  The model validations will will prevent the record from saving and you should already be displaying model errors on the views.  Take a look at the rails guides on this, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html